# In selenium webdriver Actual text is "Indian" but element.getText() is fetching �Indian�

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is source code of the element

```html
<div id="q1">
<p>Are you an "Indian" by birth</p>
</div>
```

expected_text = Are you an "Indian" by birth?
actual_text = `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='q1']/p")).getText();`

actual_text is giving Are you an `�Indian�` by birth and my assertion is getting failing unnecessarily. Can any 1 please help me how to handle this

It was working fine till the last hour. But it is giving the same error from 90minutes

Comment: Seems like an encoding problem. Try encoding the string in UTF-8 such as https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-encode-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be replacing the char.

```
s1='Are you an �Indian� by birth' 
s2=s1.replace("�","" ) 
print(s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can replace the encoded character or
you can change the webdriver language
I use Chrome

```
browserProfile = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        browserProfile.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})  
        browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=browserProfile)
```

Let me know if its work or not.